# Powershell Creates Different Zip File?

Tags: powershell, zip, md5, compress-archive

I'm creating a zip file from a directory in two ways in Win10.

The first method using "Right-Click...Send To...Compressed (zipped) folder"

The second method using Powershell Compress-Archive.  I wanted to automate the process using Powershell.

The zip file is a library to be imported into the Arduino IDE.

The first method will import into the Arduino IDE correctly.  The second method does not import correctly.

**Now before you say this is a Arduino problem please continue to read.**

So to make sure the files are the same I used Powershell to generated MD5 checksums for both files. **To my surprise they were different!!**

**The only difference I have found are the size of the created zip files.**  They are created from the same source files.

**Why are they different?**  I can manually unzip both files by "Double-Clicking and Extract All" within File Explorer

Thank you for any advice/help. John.

Here is output of the powershell script...

Directory: C:\file1
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       05/16/2020     17:18           **1948** t_OS.zip

Algorithm : MD5
Hash      : **19249C2BB9B50E827A77F7A2952EFF6D**
Path      : C:\file1\t_OS.zip

Directory: C:\file2
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       05/16/2020     19:23           **1724** t_OS.zip

Algorithm : MD5
Hash      : **2BF7B111F54FC0555E6CA64719AD350F**
Path      : C:\file2\t_OS.zip

...

```
#
# sourceFiles are what I need to be zipped. It contains the 
# directory t_OS and I need to create t_OS.zip
#
$sourceDir   = "C:\sourceFiles" 
$sourceFiles = "C:\sourceFiles\t_OS"
# file1 zip was created by right-clicking on the directory t_OS
# in the $sorceDir and selecting Send To, then 
# Compressed (zipped) folder.  This file was then moved to...
# 
$file1 = "C:\file1\t_OS.zip"

# file2 zip is created by powershell using Compress-Archive below.
$file2 = "C:\file2\t_OS.zip"

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $sourceDir -Name -Recurse

If (Test-Path $file2)   {Remove-Item $file2}

Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $file2 -CompressionLevel Fastest -Path $sourceFiles

Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $file1
Get-FileHash -Path $file1 -Algorithm MD5

Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $file2
Get-FileHash -Path $file2 -Algorithm MD5
```

...

Comment: PowerShell may use another compression method or another compression level. ZIPs can be very different ([see more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format))).

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? I'm having the exact same problem now.

Comment: @Reaver, I did not find a solution, but I did find the problem.  Looking at both zip files there is a  directory line that is missing in the powershell zip file that was expected by the Arduino IDE.  In my example, the powershell created zip was missing t_OS/src.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the two zip files are different sizes can have a number of reasons. Here are a few

1. As already mentioned, the two zip files could be using different compression algorithms. Given the small size of the resultant zip files, it may be that one is storing the data compressed, while the other is storing it uncompressed.
2. There are a number of extensions that have been added to zip files over the years that have added things like more accurate timestamps. Those add more bytes the the resultant zip files, but they shouldn't prevent the file from being uncompressed. I believe a "right-click" created zip file on Windows 10 doesn't use any of these extensions. Not sure about Powershell.

Do you have access to a Linux setup? There are tools on it that can analyse the structure of zip files.

Also, can you share the Powershell command line you used to create the zip file?

**Edit**

On your Ubuntu setup, start by checking what `unzip` thinks about the two files

```
unzip -t t_OS.zip
```

If `unzip` finds an issue it will report it.

If that doesn't work run `zipdetails` against both zip files and update your question with the results.

```
zipdetais -v t_OS.zip
```

If you don't have `zipdetails` on your Ubuntu setup, get it from [here](https://github.com/pmqs/zipdetails)

Comment: Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $file2 -Path $sourceFiles

Comment: Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $file2 -CompressionLevel Fastest -Path $sourceFiles

Comment: Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $file2 -CompressionLevel Optimal $file2 -Path $sourceFiles

Comment: Nothing in those commands look like they would result is zip file that would be non-standard enough to not be accessed by any standard zip library/utility.Do you have access to a Linux setup?

Comment: I do have a Ubuntu LTS VM

Comment: @JohnSawyers Answer updated with suggestion on testing on Ubuntu.

Comment: pmqs...Will do today.  Thanks for the suggestion.